# How to complete "Get Upgraded" mission.

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have the mission "Upgrade levels 1 times, and feel the power surge within". Now I've upgraded multiple levels but I still haven't finished the mission. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that my upgrading finally worked when I didn't use the Upgrader but my own bux and I upgraded from lvl 1 to lvl 2...

But the game is still full of bugs, so it's possible that in your case it's gonna be more difficult to get this mission right...

Comment: On Android I just finished this mission and it worked with a VIP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that is right. You need to use your own imperial bux to upgrade to complete the Emperor's mission. In a way, he is "training" you to know what are your options in the game.

The upgrader didn't work for me, but paying for it did.

Comment: On the PC version, you currently can only complete the "Get Upgraded" mission by using your Bux. If you use the upgrader VIP, the Emperor will not notice. I've done that as well, and was irritated that the Upgrader VIP didn't count towards completing the mission.

Comment: @StarPilot This is a bug, on android it works fine using the upgrader VIP

Comment: iOS - same bug.